# Is it possible to not expose my directory where I upload images?

Tags: php, image, security

In my website people can upload their photos. And I show them. Is it possible, that they would not be able to see url where that image is?

Photos are shown like this `<img src="http://mywebsite.com/my_images/image_name.gif" />`. What I want to do, that people couldn't see that `src` link. Is there any way to show photos from that directory without exposing directory name?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to hide the directory name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't, but you can use URL rewriting (apache's `mod_rewrite` or a custom PHP script to serve the images) to hide the actual location on your web server.

For example for the latter approach you coud have a `serveimage.php` on the server, which is called like `serveimage.php?file=file1.jpg`.

Comment: ...and make sure to validate the file names. Take the whitelist approach: allow only a fixed set of characters and remove everything else.

Comment: It is also a good idea to reference the file by an id, not the real name. That way you are safe against any file-inclusion attacks and you need not disclose the filename. The mapping can be stored in a database for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can call another php-script via `<img src="...">` the script loads the image and generates it. [This](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/emitimage.html) FAQ entry should help.